# How can I isolate a JPNLP (web deploy) Java version from other, legacy versions on the computer?

Tags: java, jdk, java-web-start

I have a JNLP that runs the following shortcut when installing:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\javaws.exe" -localfile`
- `C:\Users\akelly\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\42\10b90faa-1bccb6f4`

I would like to install other versions of Java for different applications.

How should I integrate JNLP versions into my desktop planning?

Answer (score 0):

I've found it pretty much impossible to isolate Java web start versions. I have one program that fails if Java 1.8 is installed unless I:

- Edit the .jnlp file (which I had to save locally) to specify the version
- Launch all the following commands from the target JVM specifically

  - `javaws -uninstall`
  - `javaws -clearcache`
  - wait 30 seconds
  - `javaws -uninstall`
  - `javaws -clearcache`
  - wait 10 seconds
  - `javaws (path to edited .jnlp file)`